# FB API for Windows Phone not clear

Tags: c#, facebook, api, windows-phone-8, facebook-access-token

I am trying to make FB login for my Windows Phone 8 app. I am following this link provided by Facebook https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-for-windows-phone
I got the to part where I login. It says to use this:

```
fbconnect://authorize?
   client_id=675854675761202&
   scope=basic_info,user_photos&
   redirect_uri=msft-4ce6ab44b7f9442482de17535b713cde%3a%2f%2fauthorize
```

I use this C# code:

```
string u = @"fbconnect://authorize?
                      client_id=444156999053911&
                      scope=public_profile,email&
                      redirect_uri=msft-45cbb27beb5a4b70abbbb82df9cfcb69://authorize";
var uri = new Uri(u);
var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
//success happenes to be bool
```

Then, FB says

***Handling Login Dialog response***

If someone successfully logs in, the URI association of your app will be automatically triggered, meaning they will be sent to your app, along with an access token:

msft-{ProductID}://authorize/?access_token={user-access-token}&expires_in={expiration-time-of-token}

What is this? How do I use it?

Comment: Take a look at [this blog post](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/integrating-facebook-in-your-windows-phone-app-using-the-facebook-app/)

Comment: Did that solve your issue? Should I add that as an answer?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem @mkdavor?

Answer (score 0):

This is the authorize response URL. You should parse it and save the access token value from the URL parameter `access_token`. With this, you can later request the Graph API from your app.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Comment: I get it, but how to obtain the response URL? All I get as a response is a boolean variable telling me if I have a successful login or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your app for the msft-{ProductID} URI scheme. The msdn documentation here  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_URIassociations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_URIassociations) goes over how to Register for a URI scheme.

You'll basically have to add this to your WMAppManifest.xml file:

```
<Extensions>
  <Protocol Name="msft-{ProductID}" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_default" />
</Extensions>
```

Remember to replace {ProductID} with the GUID product ID associated with your app.

Comment: Okay, but what after that? How do I obtain my access token? That is what concerns me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [great blog tutorial](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/integrating-facebook-in-your-windows-phone-app-using-the-facebook-app/) on logging into Facebook on your phone. It utilizes the the Facebook SDK and gives you step-by-step instructions. I won't bother trying to explain it all in this answer, it's best to read [the blog](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/integrating-facebook-in-your-windows-phone-app-using-the-facebook-app/).

Comment: In that blog post, they have me adding a new SessionStorage class by pasting code. But when I add it to the project , I get errors: "The type or namespace name 'FacebookSession' could not be found ...". Am I missing any part of the process?